# Sun damaged polyurethane-finished dining table

Tags: wood-repair, polyurethane, refinishing

So I have this Italian made marquetry dining table which has a polyurethane finish. I acquired this as a used item and I noticed after purchase that in the light I can see streaked areas where it has been in full sun and has the same appearance as if it has ring (water) damage. Is there a product that will rejuvenate the finish or do I have to cut it back and refinish?

Comment: Pics would be a great help here to have a better idea what course of action to suggest. Just generally, poly is often taken to be a finish that won't allow refinishing (easily, or at all) and many users report they haven't been able to successfully recoat it, that the new layer won't bond well and easily delaminates or scrapes off. However, it is possible so sometimes it's not necessary to go back to bare wood and refinish from scratch.

Comment: Sun damage should not be streaky.  Can possibly look like shadows, there was something on the table for years.